# Saving ArrayList Item

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, save

I am creating an application in which I have to refer to the same data over and over. I am new to coding so I don't know if I am doing it correctly. Right now I made a class with setters and getters to store the data that I want.

(The Item Class)

```
    public class PlayerList {
    private String score;
    private String team;
    private String name;
    private String scoreWeek;
    private String position;
    private String goals;
    private String assists;
    private String yellowCards;
    private String redCards;
    private int iconID;
    public PlayerList(String name, String team, String score, String scoreWeek, String position,
            String goals, String assists, String yellowCards, String redCards, int iconID){
        super();
        this.score= score;
        this.team = team;
        this.name = name;
        this.scoreWeek = scoreWeek;
        this.position= position;
        this.goals = goals;
        this.assists = assists;
        this.yellowCards = yellowCards;
        this.redCards = redCards;
        this.iconID= iconID;
    }
    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public String getTeam() {
        return team;
    }
    public void setTeam(String team) {
        this.team = team;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getScoreWeek() {
        return scoreWeek;
    }
    public void setScoreWeek(String scoreWeek) {
        this.scoreWeek = scoreWeek;
    }
    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
    public String getGoals() {
        return goals;
    }
    public void setGoals(String goals) {
        this.goals = goals;
    }
    public String getAssists() {
        return assists;
    }
    public void setAssists(String assists) {
        this.assists = assists;
    }
    public String getYellowCards() {
        return yellowCards;
    }
    public void setYellowCards(String yellowCards) {
        this.yellowCards = yellowCards;
    }
    public String getRedCards() {
        return redCards;
    }
    public void setRedCards(String redCards) {
        this.redCards = redCards;
    }
    public int getIconID() {
        return iconID;
    }
    public void setIconID(int iconID) {
        this.iconID = iconID;
    }
}
```

Then I made another class in which this data is edited and put into an array.

(Editor Code)

```
 public class Players extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<PlayerList> stateList  = new ArrayList<PlayerList>();


    public Players(){
        PlayerList _states = new PlayerList("Name","Team","Score","Score Week", "Position",
                "Goals", "Assists","Yellow Cards","Red Cards", R.drawable.client_icon);
        stateList.add(_states);

        PlayerList _states1 = new PlayerList("Name2","Team","Score","Score Week", "Position",
                "Goals", "Assists","Yellow Cards","Red Cards", R.drawable.client_icon);
        stateList.add(_states1);

        PlayerList _states2 = new PlayerList("Name3","Team","Score","Score Week", "Position",
                "Goals", "Assists","Yellow Cards","Red Cards", R.drawable.client_icon);
        stateList.add(_states2);

    }
}
```

After editing the data and adding it to a separate array List, how can I refer back to the data. For example in a other section of the application I need to refer to the Score of a player? I wanted to save the data in SharedPreferences but it only saves sets. Please Help.  I want to send it to another activity. For example I want it to show the player score on the home screen. As well as on a screen that talks about the players on a team.

Comment: What do you mean with another section of the application?. Is your problem sending the data to another Activity, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to pass your data directly to your the function that uses it, you have to persist it somewhere. This is called **data persistence**. It typically means that the process will die before the data it created. In Java, the term is used loosely to refer to data persisting between events or even method calls, not necessarily processes. In Java, persistence is commonly accomplished using serialization. You can make your class `Serializable` like this

`public class MyClass implements Serializable { }`

An object can only be made serializable if every object it contains is serializable. Once an object is serializable, it can be written to and read from a stream (maybe to a file). Other code can then retrieve the serialized data. `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` are capable of reading and writing serializable data. You'll have to cast the objects as you read them back to the appropriate type.

If I read your question wrong and you really just didn't know how to access your `ArrayList`, try this:

```
int score = null;
for (PlayerList pl: myArrayList) {
    if(pl.getName() == teamName)
        score = pl.getScore();
}
System.out.println(score == null ? "No score available.": score);
```

Or, to get the score of all of your teams:

```
for (PlayerList pl: myArrayList) {
    System.out.println(pl.getScore());
}
```

Comment: you have syntax errors(missing `;`). Also `score` is private so you need to used a getter method to access it.

Comment: @Sionnach733 I reconstructed the first bit of code after you brought my attention to it, since I previously missed the point of what the OP was trying to accomplish. I'm 95% sure he doesn't care at all about persistence, and just wants Stack to do his homework.